# Can't apply Css style to React-datetime using className

Tags: reactjs, react-datetime

I am trying to add border-radius: 5px to React-datetime component using className but not working.

E.g:

```
  import ReactDateTime from ‘react-datetime’;

<ReactDateTime className=‘datetime’ />

 .datetime{
 border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

I know that react-datetime module provides seperate css styles. But my concern is why it is not accepting when I do using className.

Comment: Did you try defining the css in another file and importing it to the component? Are you using create react app or webpack?

Comment: Yes my css styles are in different file and included in index.html. Yes I am using webpack

Comment: If that's the case, you might want import the css with webpack and bundling it just like you do the JS files, though you'd need a loader for that, `style-loader` and `css-loader`.

Answer (score 5):

Try using inputProps with className as like below. It should work.

```
<DateTime inputProps={{className:'datetime'}} />
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked well. I am able to apply styles using inputProps. You saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add `!important` like :

```
.datetime{
    border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

If it doesn't work it could probably be an override problem.

You will have probably to check here :
https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime/blob/master/example/react-datetime.css

If it doesn't work can we see your config for this package ?
We need to have a look on your complete component and css stylesheet

Comment: Yes I tried with !important as well but not working. Sorry this is my office project I can’t share such big config file and as well component. But I inspected and changed border-radius on .form-control and it worked but through css with class name is not working. Any other suggestions please because it’s huge file and I can’t even take snapshot.

Comment: Have you try to use "double quotes" instead of this : ‘ ’  ?

Comment: Yes I tried with double quotes but it didn’t work. It worked with inputProps.